# LC Driver burned Mosfet

Tags: mosfet, oscillator, resonant

I am using this circuit to drive my LC tank for my metal detector,
[image: Schematics]
PWM is from esp8266, 3V3 max, operating frequency 6.1kHz, inducatance and capacitance are for reference (but are close enough)

It was working fine and only consumed 40mA so I removed the heatsink from Mosfet P40NF03L and decided to test it before I made any further modifications, felt wires slighty warm so tested power consumption, now it was 800mA

My mosfet got burned, Drain to Source have permanent resistance of 20-Ohms

I have plenty 80NF70 Mosfets those I can try next but fear they might also go bad, what might have happened? Coil have internal DC resistance of around 8-Ohms so it can't be the initial pulse of Amps that burned it?

P40NF03L was my precious rare gem, would operate fine from 3.3v, not sure about 80NF70 as it has Vgs range of 2V to 4V min to max

What can I do to protect my Mosfet in future? Also open to entirely new design

LTSpice simulation, <s>Blue</s> (Red): Voltage at Drain, Green: Current at drain
[image]

Comment: 80NF70 is not likely to reliably work with only 3.3V gate drive. It's Vgs **threshold** is 2-4V - that's the point where it just barely starts to turn on, not the point where it acts like a closed switch.

Comment: 1k resistor on the gate? Seems way too high for a device with a large gate capacitance. Should be more like 22R. 30V seems a little low for the voltage - it’s a resonant circuit, so high voltages may be produced.

Comment: I think you should simulate this circuit to see what currents flow into the drain and what drain voltages are produced.

Comment: 180 us or 6.1kHz and 3.3V are all wrong. what are result do you expect?

Comment: Vgs(th) has a NTC (-ve tempco) thus the RdsOn will rise even more with high surge pulses from the low ESR cap.   With  6.4W power drain and no heatsink  and Rja = 62.5'C/W the junction will ramp towards meltdown.  You may want a narrow duty cycle with 8V pulse instead.,

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I expect it to make my coil resonate which maybe was working till nmos decided to quit its job

Comment: 22R means 150mA at 3.3V, next thing to burn could be my microcontroller if I try that @Kartman

Comment: > asim Ciss =2550 pF so that 22R suggested by @Kartman actually matches RdsOn of many logic , which is ideal for clean edges but charge time is only a few microseconds at Rg=1k so overdamped is not a huge issue so compromise to 220R.  What duty cycle did you use to damage FET and what is ESR of Cap?  3.3V is incorrect drive voltage. Use 2x Vgs(th) max or more.

Comment: 6.1kHz freq and duty cycle was 50%, can I use npn transistor to drive mosfet like normally turned on nmos which is turned off by npn when pwm is high, increasing duty cycle so nmos mostly off? @TonyStewartEE75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use many different transistors NPN, PNP, Nch , Pch in many combinations of amplifying voltage and current such that the drivers are efficient.

This is a metal detector and shown with such a simple parallel resonance circuit, more important is how to detect metals with a change in magnetic field intensity.

When the switch is on, it is short-circuiting the high impedance resonance.

What is the frequency for maximum dominant real and reactive power being applied?
What are the limiting factors to pulse current?
- Is it 6.1kHz or is it the frequency where the half cycle matches the pulse width?
- That all depends on your choice of LC resonance. But since power is only being supplied during the pulse width, this must be the dominant factor for sensitivity to  resonance.

- The voltage will increase and current will reduce rapidly  with the reduction of C, but when the resonant frequency matches \$1/(2T_{PW50})\$ you will have maximum gain and sensitivity to magnetic field changes but also electric field from moisture.
- So choose the frequency and thus pulse width wisely based on the experience of commercial metal detectors for gold, copper aluminum and steel.
- the choose the best shape of the loop.  A double D is most common.

Comment: I was working on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609965/dc-offset-and-amplifier when this happened, this is just a test double d coil, I will build a better one in future when I am done with theory part

Comment: Yes you can use a low RdsON FET or a power transistor and diode  or smart switch. But what is the best way to detect a change in permeability?  https://tinyurl.com/y8z8l3ws

Comment: D1878 is fast but no good for hFE. A switch will reduce hFE to about 10% of max  , D718 is good but equivalent to 0.5 Ohm at Vce(sat)

Comment: I meant directly using NPN and ditching NMOS entirely? @Tony

Comment: Average power is simply peak power * duty cycle.  What differences do you notice here? https://tinyurl.com/y84oc7q5  I only changed 1 parameter

Comment: tried using BC547 at the gate of 80NF70, does not work, tried using D718 only, it gives up at 3.5kHz max but consumes less amps, I am loosing hope

Comment: Just for an update I used apm2509 smd mosfet from old graphics card, it not only works but increased stability and sensitivity of my detector, has vds max 25V which is scary